# How to generate a monthly report for multiple years?

Tags: reports

I would like to generate a report that shows monthly breakdowns for last 4-5 years. Is there a shortcut to do it? thanks

Comment: what you want to show in reports? and which report are you looking for?

Comment: Just a cumulative total in every month, contribution report.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Report plus](https://civicrm.org/extensions/reportplus) extension, it does provide some reports grouped by contribution date in month or year may be Contribution Summary Plus or Contribution Matrix Plus

Comment: Default "Contribution Summary" report did the trick. But thanks for the answer anyway. Probably will be helpful some other time.